# How to ensure that all Async functions Run before defer is executed

Tags: unit-testing, go, asynchronous, gomock

I have a function say

```
Myfunction() {  
      x.RunAsync() //Async Function call 
}
```

I have to write a test case for `Myfunction()`. I am using go-mock for this. Also  have mocked `x`.

```
Test_MyFunction() {
   mockCtrl := gomock.NewController(t)
   defer mockCtrl.Finish()
   //EXPECT() call to stub RunAsync()
}
```

Problem now is my test runs successfully, but somehow at the end it panics saying, that call to `mockX.RunAsync()` is missing.
I think this is because defer is being executed before my RunAsync was stubbed.
How do I ensure that all Async functions run before defer is executed.

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense - the only "async function call" in Go is `go <function>`, which doesn't appear in the code shown. And the way to wait for some number of goroutines before continuing execution of some function would be a `sync.WaitGroup`.

Comment: `RunAsync()` function implements this, I did not explicitly mention it.

Comment: If you've mocked `x` then the mock's `RunAsync` needn't run asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the test double is being used as a stub, then you should call `.AnyTimes()` on it. This way gomock won't care if the go routine has finished or not.

If however you are wanting to make assertions on it (and therefore its a mock and not a stub), then you need to ensure the go routine has executed before letting the test finish.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Since it is a stub, I can use this. But what if it was otherwise?

Comment: Check out https://medium.com/@poy/gomock-and-go-routines-6a7c01d989d5 for some advice.

Comment: In accordance of your article : What if Bar() returns something. If we put Return() additionally, it shows error. Also if you use DoAndReturn(), then also it says too many argument error.

Comment: type Foo interface {
 Bar (arg1 Arg1, arg2 chan *Arg2) (*ReturnArg, error)
}

Comment: Sorry I am very new to Go!

Comment: so, if I put Do and Return both it says `too many arguments for function call`

Comment: File an issue with github.com/golang/mock and we can continue the conversation there (It will be easier to paste code and such).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185371/discussion-between-arushi-and-poy).